# How do I progress the Season of the Hunt Ratcatcher Triumph?

Tags: destiny-2

I noticed the [Ratcatcher Triumph](https://www.light.gg/db/legend/triumphs/2952387718/ratcatcher/) in my list as `22/25`, but I don't recall what I was doing when I got that progress.

[image: Ratcatcher]

I have equipped both Europa set armour and also Season of the Hunt armour pieces, and tried killing yellow bar boss Fallen enemies in the open world, whilst rescuing the skiff, which spawns three bosses and got no progress.

[image: Character armour]

I tried completing the Kridis Empire Hunt to see if a hunt boss would progress it, but that did not work either.

What activity do I need to do in order to progress this Triumph? It can clearly be progressed before the seasons starts on Tuesday 17 Nov 2020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the season has now launched this triumph is now progressing for me as normal, although I think I am getting more progress from Hive than Fallen.

The new Wrathborn Hunts are a good way to tackle this triumph.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I was able to complete the triumph before the season started. I was just defeating enemies in Europa and randomly got it. Wonder if it was a bug or something